# How to rename the x axis label bar?

Tags: excel, pandas, dataframe, matplotlib, bar-chart

I imported my excel sheet into python to create a bar graph. But i want my x-axis label bar to be changed to the respective months (Jan, Feb, Mar, Apr, May, Jun, Jul) instead of the numbers they assigned for me (0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6). How do i change it? Attached is what my excel sheet looks like. [Passengers](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VsKrA.png)

```
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

passengers_df = pd.read_excel('/Users/name/Downloads/ECA.xlsx','Passengers')
print(passengers_df)

passengers_df.plot()

plt.xlabel('Months')
plt.ylabel('Passengers Carried (\'000)')
plt.title('Number of passengers carried per month')

plt.show()
```

Comment: @JohanC you should post your answer as an answer, not as a comment

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can set the xticklabels with

```
plt.xticks((0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6), ('Jan', 'Feb', 'Mar', 'Apr', 'May', 'Jun', 'Jul'))
```

Note that whenever setting the tick labels, it's useful to also set the corresponding tick positions.

In the case of a Pandas dataframe, normally the index is used automatically for labeling the x-axis. So, you could explicitly set the index to the first column:

```py
passengers_df.set_index(passengers_df.columns[0], inplace=True)
passengers_df.plot()
```